# fadeToggle div which is my menu

Tags: jquery

I have a menu which comes on and off with fadeToggle and this works good. But I want that when the user clicks anywhere that the menu will fade out and it may only fadeIn when the menu button is clicked. I've tried this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "body" ).click(function() {
   $( "#menubalk" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
   });
 });
});
```

But when I click the menu button it will dissapear right after it appeared. Is there an option that I can say $("Everyting except #menubutton").click or does such thing not exist? Or does someone have an better option?

Kind regards,

Job

Answer (score 0):

You can user `not` in JQuery like below:

```
$('body').not('#exceptID').click(function(){
      //rest of code
});
```

There is an alternative way:

```
$('body:not(#exceptID)').click(function(){
    //rest of code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery's [is method](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "body" ).click(function(evt) {
  if $(evt.target).is("#menubalk") {
    $( "#menubalk" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {});
   }
 });
});
```